Prettier error when formatting Apex classes: spawnSync EINVAL
I helped set up Prettier for a colleague yesterday and this morning I found my Prettier started dumping EINVAL errors for Apex classes. I can run Prettier just fine on javascript files for LWCs, but I can't figure out what's causing the EINVAL on Apex.
So far, I've

Deleted the repository from my machine.
Cloned the repository from the remote.
Removed the package.json file.
Freshly installed prettier and prettier-plugin-apex from npm

I've seen that a Node security update that impacted Windows users may be related to this issue. However, I have not updated Windows this week nor restarted my computer since the last time I used Prettier successfully.
The only thing I updated today before running into this issue was the GitHub Pull Requests extension for VS Code which restarted and updated VS Code itself.
EINVAL Error Log
["ERROR" - 11:26:47 AM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 11:26:47 AM] spawnSync c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier-plugin-apex\vendor\apex-ast-serializer\bin\apex-ast-serializer.bat EINVAL
Error: spawnSync c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier-plugin-apex\vendor\apex-ast-serializer\bin\apex-ast-serializer.bat EINVAL
    at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1124:20)
    at spawnSync (node:child_process:914:24)
    at parseTextWithSpawn (c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier-plugin-apex\dist\src\parser.js:47:59)
    at Object.parse (c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier-plugin-apex\dist\src\parser.js:472:25)
    at Object.parse (c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier\index.js:7515:23)
    at coreFormat (c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier\index.js:8829:18)
    at formatWithCursor2 (c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier\index.js:9021:18)
    at c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier\index.js:38183:12
    at Object.format (c:\Users\luke\Git\sfdc\node_modules\prettier\index.js:38197:12)
    at t.PrettierMainThreadInstance.format (c:\Users\luke\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.4.0\dist\extension.js:1:18227)
    at t.default.format (c:\Users\luke\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.4.0\dist\extension.js:1:16318)
    at async t.PrettierEditProvider.provideEdits (c:\Users\luke\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.4.0\dist\extension.js:1:12876)
    at async W.provideDocumentFormattingEdits (c:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:154:109702)
["INFO" - 11:26:47 AM] Formatting completed in 22ms.

package.json
{
  "name": "sfdc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This guide helps Salesforce developers who are new to Visual Studio Code go from zero to a deployed app using Salesforce Extensions for VS Code and Salesforce CLI.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "3.3.3",
    "prettier-plugin-apex": "2.1.4"
  }
}

Node, NPM, and Java Versions
$ node --version
v22.5.1
$ npm --version
10.8.2
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.11 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 17.0.11+9-adhoc..jdk17u)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 17.0.11+9-adhoc..jdk17u, mixed mode, sharing)


Turned it off and back on again
Shut off my computer last night and turned it back on again this morning. Prettier now formats Apex class files. No spawnSync EINVAL error.
Not sure what the problem was exactly but at least my Prettier is working again.
